# Vue.js issue with access to properties of dynamically generated (based on Vuex data) table cells

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image: Gantt Table]

And after adding the hint header
`<h4>Click to change the Table's Mode and to wait for 2 second</h4>`
I see different unexpected results:

[image: Variance 2]

[image: Variance 3]

For emulation of delay with asynchronous computed property (similar to receiving data from Vuex or AJAX request) I use ***sleepForDebug()*** function:

```
sleepForDebug(delay) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
}
```

I have couple of questions:
1. Why watch: ***newTasks(tasks)*** doesn't trigger first time and the line doesn't appear
2. Why `let startRef = "cell"+task.start;` is **undefined** in a next line: `this.$refs[startRef][0];`

```
watch: {
  newTasks(tasks) {
    console.log("watch: newTasks()-------------");
    console.log(tasks);
    this.tasks = tasks;
    this.$forceUpdate();
  }
},
```

2. https://jsfiddle.net/AlexPilugin/98b0pw24/106/

   ```js
   Vue.config.productionTip = false;
   Vue.config.devtools=false;
   new Vue({
     el: "#app",
     data: {
       longMode: false,
       columns: 7,
       tasks: []
     },
     created() {
       this.tasks = this.newTasks;
     },
     watch: {
       newTasks(tasks) {
         this.tasks = tasks;
         this.$forceUpdate();
       }
     },
     computed: {
       newTasks() {
         let tasks = null;
         if(this.longMode) {
           tasks = [
             {start: 0, end: 3},
             {start: 2, end: 5},
             {start: 1, end: 7}
           ];
         } else {
           tasks = [
             {start: 0, end: 4},
             {start: 2, end: 6}
           ];
         }
         this.sleepForDebug(2000);
         return tasks;
         /*
         this.delay(2000).then(() => {
           console.log("return new tasks:");
           console.log(tasks);
           return tasks;
         })
         */
       }
     },
     methods: {
       toggle() {
         this.longMode = !this.longMode;
         this.columns = this.longMode ? 14 : 7;
         this.tasks = this.newTasks;
         //console.log("clicked! longMode: " + this.longMode);
       },
       sleepForDebug(delay) {
         var start = new Date().getTime();
         while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
       },
        delay(t) {
         return new Promise(function(resolve) {
           setTimeout(resolve, t)
         });
       },
       getLineStyle() {
       /*
        * The HTMLElement.offsetTop read-only property returns the distance of the current element relative to the top of the offsetParent node.    
        * getBoundingClientRect() is a very useful, cross browser safe method that returns top, right, bottom, and left position of any element relative to the viewport.
        */
         let styleObject = {left: 0, top: 5, width: 0};
         let rowIndex = 2;
         //console.log("getLineStyle("+rowIndex+"): ------------------");
         //console.log(this.$refs);
         if(this.newTasks && this.newTasks.length>0) {
           //console.log(this.newTasks);
           let task = this.newTasks[rowIndex];
           if(task) {
             //console.log("task:");
             //console.log(task);
             //let start = task.start; //<---- this.$refs[startRef][0] NOT WORKING
             //let end = task.end; //<---- this.$refs[endRef][0] NOT WORKING
             let start = 0;
             let end = 6;
             let startRef = 'cell'+start;
             let endRef = 'cell'+end;
             let startElement = this.$refs[startRef][0];
             let endElement = this.$refs[endRef][0];
             let startLeft = Math.floor(startElement.offsetLeft);
             let endLeft = Math.floor(endElement.offsetLeft);
             let ofsetTop = Math.floor(startElement.getBoundingClientRect().top);
             let taskWidth = (endLeft - startLeft);
             //console.log("startLeft: "+startLeft + ", endLeft: " +endLeft + ", ofsetTop:" +ofsetTop);
             styleObject = {left: startLeft+"px", top: ofsetTop+"px", width: taskWidth+"px"};
             
             //console.log("startElement ClientRect:");
             //console.log(startElement.getBoundingClientRect());
             //console.log("endElement ClientRect:");
             //console.log(endElement.getBoundingClientRect());
           }

           //console.log("styleObject:");
           //console.log(styleObject);
           return styleObject;
         }
       }
     }
   })
   ```

   ```css
   body {
   background: #20262E;
   padding: 20px;
   font-family: Helvetica;
   }

   #app {
   background: #fff;
   border-radius: 4px;
   padding: 20px;
   transition: all 0.2s;
   }

   table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   table-layout: auto;
   /*fixed;*/
   border: 1px solid #012656;
   }

   .cell {
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #012656;
   cursor: pointer;
   }

   td.cell:nth-child(7n-1),
   td.cell:nth-child(7n) {
   background: #eee;
   }

   .line {
   position: absolute;
   top: 4px;
   height: 6px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   background: red;
   overflow: hidden;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
   <div id="app">
     <h4>Click to change the Table's Mode and to wait for 2 second</h4>
       <table class="gantt-table" @click="toggle">
         <tr>
           <td 
             v-for="(cell, colIndex) in columns" 
             :ref="'cell'+colIndex" 
             :key="'col-'+colIndex" 
             class="cell"
           >
             {{ colIndex }}
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr 
           v-show="newTasks && newTasks.length > 0" 
           v-for="(row, rowIndex) in newTasks" 
           :key="'tr-'+rowIndex"
         >   
           <div 
             v-show="newTasks && newTasks.length > 0" 
             style="position: relative;"
           >
             <div class="line" :style="getLineStyle()"></div>
           </div>  
     
           <td 
             v-for="(cell, colIndex) in columns" 
             :key="'row-'+rowIndex+'col-'+colIndex" 
             class="cell"
           >
             <div>&nbsp&nbsp</div>
           </td>
         </tr>
       </table>
     </div>
   ```

Comment: About question 1: "Doesn't trigger first time" - first time when? After render, first button click? Please clarify. About question 2: What exactly is undefined? `startRef` or `this.$refs[startRef]` or `this.$refs[startRef][0]` ?

Comment: Hi MarcRo. 1. Now I understood about: this.tasks = this.newTasks; - there is no new value in that moment.

Comment: 2. If to change the code: <tr v-for="(row, rowNumber) in newTasks" ...> and:  :style="getLineStyle(rowNumber)" - rowNumber is undefined

Comment: The idea is next - the table will have the same number of rows as value of newTasks.length and each line should represent the start date of task and the end date of a task on each row (each row is a task). I need to get a rowNumber and based on this number to get property of the line on each row.